# object array index value is being overided by the preceding index value

Tags: java

This is an odd situation for me, I just started learning Java OOP.

I made a class looks like this

```
public class Student {
        public static String name;
        public static int marks;

        public Student(String n, int m){
            name = n;
            marks = m;
        }
        public static void printProperties(){
            System.out.println("Name = " + name + " , marks = " + m);
        }
    }
```

As you can see the constructor accepts two data: name and marks.

in my main method

```
      System.out.println("Please enter number of students:");
            int n = scan.nextInt();

            Student[] stu = new Student[n];

            String name;
            int marks = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < stu.length; i++){

                System.out.println("Please enter name for student #" + (i+1));
                name = scan.next();

                System.out.println("Please enter marks for student #" + (i+1));
                marks  = scan.nextInt();

                stu[i] = new Student(name,marks);

                System.out.println();
            }

//Display
            for(int x = 0; x < stu.length; x++){
                System.out.println("#" + (x+1) + " Name: " + stu[x].name + ", Marks: " + stu[x].marks);

            }
```

So my output as follows:

```
Please enter number of students:
2
Please enter name for student #1
tom
Please enter age for student #1
20

Please enter name for student #2
billy
Please enter age for student #2
80

#1 Name: billy, Marks: 80
#2 Name: billy, Marks: 80
```

It should be:

```
   #1 Name: tom, Marks: 20
   #2 Name: billy, Marks: 80
```

Why is the preceding index value overidding its previous index value?

Comment: Please show the code within `Student`. I wonder whether you're using static variables, for example...

Comment: please post your Student class to look how are u using values in constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should work absolutely fine, if your Student class looks something like this :

```
public class Student{
    String name;
    int marks;
    public Student(String name, int marks){
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

EDITED :

This is what Jon Skeet mentioned.

You are using static variables which are **class level variables**, so they are overridden every time you assign value to them and only the last value is retained.

You need instance variables here.

Comment: beat me to it. I would add that the String name and int marks in his main should be declared inside the loop at assignment time, just to ensure the global variables arent being assigned incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **static** , simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Do not make your fields `static`, and let's use `private` to control access -

```
public class Student {
    private String name; // not static, and use private.
    private int marks;

    public Human(String n, int m){
        name = n;
        marks = m;
    }
    public void printProperties(){ // also should not be static.
        System.out.println("Name = " + name + " , marks = " + m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A **static variable** belongs to the entire class. It is one variable that is shared among all of the objects. So when you change that variable, it changes it for all the objects.

Instead, define `name` and `marks` as **instance variables**. In other words, remove the `static` modifier from your variable declarations. An instance variable is unique to each object. Each object has its own copy of an instance variable.

Also, it's good practice to declare `name` and `marks` as `private`. Then create getters and setters for those variables. This hides the implementation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student{

    private String name;
    private int marks;

    public String getName() {  //getter
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {  //setter
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMarks() {  //getter
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {  //setter
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Student(String n, int m){
        name = n;
        marks = m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter number of students:");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        Student[] stu = new Student[n];

        String name;
        int marks = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < stu.length; i++){

            System.out.println("Please enter name for student #" + (i+1));
            name = scan.next();

            System.out.println("Please enter marks for student #" + (i+1));
            marks  = scan.nextInt();

            stu[i] = new Student(name,marks);

            System.out.println();
        }

        //Display
        for(int x = 0; x < stu.length; x++){
            System.out.println("#" + (x+1) + " Name: " + stu[x].getName() + ", Marks: " + stu[x].getMarks());

        }

        scan.close();
    }


}
```